# Statement about an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Accidentally found such statement about an alternating series:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}b_n, \: b_n > 0$, is convergent if 
$$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac{p}{n} + o\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big),\; p > 0$$

How to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} <1$ for large $n.$